# ¿Como usar RTRIM y LTRIM en sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Tengo un SP que me genera un json con la información de mis tablas, pero el dia que necesito insertaron la informacion de manera manual y cuando lo ejecuto sale con un espacio a la derecha.

Esta es la manera como debe de salir: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Esta saliendo de esta manera: [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Intente quitarselo de la siguiente manera:

```
REPLACE(RTRIM(LTRIM(a.Codigo)), ' ', '')
RTRIM(LTRIM(a.Codigo))
RTRIM(a.Codigo)
TRIM(a.Codigo)
```

Este es mi SP donde genero mi JSON:

```
SELECT ('{' + '"ShopNo": "' + s.eCommerceSucursal + '",' +
        '"Barcode": "' + a.Codigo + '",' +
        '"onHandQty": ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(ISNULL(ad.Disponible, 0))) + ',' +
        '"StockDate": "' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @Date, 120) + '",' +
        '"Cost": {' +
            '"UnitLandedCost": 0,' +
            '"UnitNetCost": ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.PrecioNeto) + ',' +
            '"UnitGrossCost": ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, a.Precio) + '},' +
        '"Country": "MEXICO",' +
        '"Currency": "MXN"' + '},') AS 'stock_data'
```

Alguien sabe si estoy realizando algo mal?¿ o si es otra sentencia para quitarlo?

Codigo copiado y pegado:
1004967049057

Comment: Solo usa :    

RTRIM(a.Codigo,' ')

Comment: Pero el string ese incluye las comillas ???

Comment: Pero asi como tu lo pones, me sale error y dice que solo debe de tener un 1 argumento

Comment: Esas comillas las añade el SP que esta creado, ya edite mi pregunta aumetando la parte de SP donde se realiza mi JSON, funiona bien, solo esta fallando en ese dia por que se inserto la informacion de manera manual.

Comment: Puede que no sea un espacio, hace un select de toda la vida a esa tabla;  copia y pega ese `Codigo` en un comentario o en la pregunta (sin cambiar nada de lo que copiaste)

Comment: Ya lo coloqué hasta el final, si es que quieres ver si hay espacios en la consulta, no hay.

Comment: Me perdí con tu último comentario. El dato está guardado con o sin espacio ?

Comment: `TRIM(a.Codigo)` debería funcionar ya que elimina espacios al principio y al final de la cadena de texto, [aquí la docu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16)

Comment: Sin espacios, ya realice eso de compiar y pegar para poder ver si viene con espacios y no me da nada.

Comment: Es que si el TRIM, LTRIM o RTRIM no funciona, lo que está ahí puede que no sea unn espacio (ASCII 32), puede que sea otro carácter parecido como  U+00A0, U+2005,  U+2009 y varios más. Yo le haría un update a esa celda reescribiendo el código

Comment: Es lo que yo tambien pensé, que con TRIM lo iba a quitar, pero me sigue trayendo el espacio

Comment: OK, intentaré eso Yussef, espero que funcione.

Comment: Me avisas si funciona!!

Answer (score 3):

[`ltrim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/ltrim-transact-sql) quita los espacios a la izquierda y [`rtrim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/rtrim-transact-sql) quita los espacios a la derecha.

Ambas son funciones que devuelven la cadena recibida sin los espacios, por lo que la forma de uso es como la de cualquier otra función.

Si estás seguro que el problema solo es a la derecha, utiliza solo `rtrim`, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT ('{' + '"ShopNo": "' + s.eCommerceSucursal + '",' +
        '"Barcode": "' + rtrim(a.Codigo) + '",' +
        '"onHandQty": ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(ISNULL(ad.Disponible, 0))) + ',' +
        bla, bla, bla
```

Si no sabes si es a la derecha o a la izquierda, puedes usarlos *anidados*, así:

```
SELECT ('{' + '"ShopNo": "' + s.eCommerceSucursal + '",' +
        '"Barcode": "' + ltrim(rtrim(a.Codigo)) + '",' +
        '"onHandQty": ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, SUM(ISNULL(ad.Disponible, 0))) + ',' +
        bla, bla, bla
```

Por otro lado, y sé que no es tu pregunta, sugiero que no formes el JSON *a mano*, SQL Server tiene un buen soporte para convertir automáticamente el resultado de una consulta a formato JSON con la cláusula [`for json`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/json/format-query-results-as-json-with-for-json-sql-server), por ejemplo:

```
SELECT s.eCommerceSucursal as ShopNo
       , ltrim(rtrim(a.Codigo)) as Barcode
       , coalesce(sum(ad.Disponible), 0) as onHandQty
       , blah, blah
  from MiTabla s
       inner join MiOtraTabla a on s.CondicionJoin = a.CondicionJoin
 where Condicion1 = A
   and Condicion2 = B
 group by a, b, c
   for JSON auto
```

Si no es un arreglo lo que necesitas, agrega la opción [`WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER`](https://learn.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/relational-databases/json/remove-square-brackets-from-json-without-array-wrapper-option)